# Where can i get this external resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jsfiddle

`I have found  This http://jsfiddle.net/YCTDQ/` useful to me to implement for my project but when i see there are library files included and i have not seen in external resources but they are included with the jsfiddle.

How can i get those 2 external resources to work them correctly.

In jsfiddle the code is showing correctly but iam unable to add the library files in the code snippet shown below.

```js
$(function(){
    $('select').combobox();
});

/* 
    Combobox widget 
    - taken from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox
    - added support for
      - default option
      - combo uses width of original select
      - autoFocus
    - removed
      - tooltips
      - setting value to "" if invalid (instead sets to default)
*/
(function ($) {
        $.widget("ui.combobox", {
            _create: function () {
                var input,
                  that = this,
                  wasOpen = false,
                  select = this.element.hide(),
                  selected = select.children(":selected"),
                  defaultValue = selected.text() || "",
                  wrapper = this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                    .addClass("ui-combobox")
                    .insertAfter(select);

                function removeIfInvalid(element) {
                    var value = $(element).val(),
                      matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(value) + "$", "i"),
                      valid = false;
                    select.children("option").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                            this.selected = valid = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    if (!valid) {
                        // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                        $(element).val(defaultValue);
                        select.val(defaultValue);
                        input.data("ui-autocomplete").term = "";
                    }
                }

                input = $("<input>")
                  .appendTo(wrapper)
                  .val(defaultValue)
                  .attr("title", "")
                  .addClass("ui-state-default ui-combobox-input")
                  .width(select.width())
                  .autocomplete({
                      delay: 0,
                      minLength: 0,
                      autoFocus: true,
                      source: function (request, response) {
                          var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                          response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                              var text = $(this).text();
                              if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                  return {
                                      label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                          "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                          $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                          ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                      value: text,
                                      option: this
                                  };
                          }));
                      },
                      select: function (event, ui) {
                          ui.item.option.selected = true;
                          that._trigger("selected", event, {
                              item: ui.item.option
                          });
                      },
                      change: function (event, ui) {
                          if (!ui.item) {
                              removeIfInvalid(this);
                          }
                      }
                  })
                  .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

                input.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $("<li>")
                      .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                      .appendTo(ul);
                };

                $("<a>")
                  .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                  .appendTo(wrapper)
                  .button({
                      icons: {
                          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                      },
                      text: false
                  })
                  .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                  .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle")
                  .mousedown(function () {
                      wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
                  })
                  .click(function () {
                      input.focus();

                      // close if already visible
                      if (wasOpen) {
                          return;
                      }

                      // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                      input.autocomplete("search", "");
                  });
            },

            _destroy: function () {
                this.wrapper.remove();
                this.element.show();
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
    .ui-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .ui-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    /* support: IE7 */
    *height: 1.7em;
    *top: 0.1em;
  }
  .ui-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
  }
```

```html
<select style="width:300px">
    <option value>-Select a number-</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
    <option value="10">Ten</option>
</select>
```

[image: where]

Comment: [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/)  and [jQueryUi](http://jqueryui.com/download/), download the libraries or use the cdn and add the according `<script />` tags in your html, if this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them here and pick which url you want.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui

Then add as script (generally in head or footer)

A example of this would be:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Additional Update:

So the two scripts are `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js` and `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js`

In your html you should have something like below to get this script to work.

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="yctdq_script.js"></script> 
<!-- you ca copy code to external file and call it yctdq_script.js or whatever you want to name it. Or you can paste it between the two script tags -->
</head>
......

<body> 
.....
<select style="width:300px">
    <option value>-Select a number-</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
    <option value="10">Ten</option>
</select>
.....
</body>
```

Comment: understand but can u edit the codesnippet for better understanding

Comment: @overflowstack9 I hope this helps you further. I edited the code to show you want you would need to do if you want to apply it to your own web page. Let me know if you have other questions and I will explain further.